# Error 403 on yii2 backend

Tags: apache, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The yii2-advanced template is used. After the transfer to production (using CentOS) on the files of scripts and styles I catch the error 403 That is, the page is given, and the styles are not tightened.

[image]
And if you go through a direct link (according to styles), then they are given correctly (response 200). What could be the reason?

Conf for backend

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName cp.tickets.site.ru
ServerAdmin osd@site.ru
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/htdocs/backend/web"
Options FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on

<Directory "/var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/htdocs/backend/web">
    RewriteEngine on
    AllowOverride none
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>


ErrorLog    /var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/logs/cp_http_error.log
TransferLog /var/www/vhost/tickets.site.ru/logs/cp_http_access.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check asset folder permisions

Comment: 777 on asset folder

Comment: Where is your asset folder?

Comment: /htdocs/backend/web/assets

Comment: If you temporarily remove .htaccess, does that solve your problem with `forbidden`?

Comment: htaccess is off. I control the rewrite through the conf of Apache

Comment: Restart xampp after adding virtual host?

Comment: yes, restarted it

Comment: [THIS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69692/forbidden-403-for-js-file-on-localhost) should help

Comment: So when you call http://cp.tickets.site.ru/assets/59e6b086/yii.js in your browser the file gets fetched?

Comment: yes. File gets fetched